# passing Xmx argument to ant script from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, jvm-arguments

Trying to pass a `-Xms` and `-Xmx` argument to Ant script that run through eclipse. But unable to pass through always getting :

```
Unknown argument: -J-Xms512m -J-Xmx1024m mytarget
Buildfile: C:\cehckout_trunk\myproject\ivy-build.xml
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 31 milliseconds

Unknown argument: -Xms512m -Xmx1024m mytarget
Buildfile: C:\cehckout_trunk\myproject\ivy-build.xml
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 31 milliseconds
```

Any quick pointer to eclipse runtime arguments for running ant script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are passing JVM arguments to Ant, not java. But the Ant executable doesn't accept JVM arguments. You should use the environment varible ANT_OPTS to specify the settings.

Here is an example:
http://wiki.apache.org/ant/TheElementsOfAntStyle

Check the

> Use ANT_OPTS to control Ant's virtual machine settings

part.

Comment: thanks! coolcfan. though this is not so direct solution. but still helped me get over for time being.

Comment: Made some changes to core build scripts so that maxmemory argument can be passed from the caller of that target. it was earlier harcoded to 128M.

Comment: Yeah, modifying the ant.bat or ant.sh should be a work around~ I think Ant should have provide a built-in property to allow user to pass memory parameter via -Dxxx=xxx, but it hasn't :P